Mergefield keep together in one word
I am having data in excel and word document. In word I have field defined {MERGEFIELD my_field @ "DD.MM.YYYY"}. I am getting result 05.01.2024 in two lines for some data (this field is dinamic because of previus dinamic names, title, jobs).
I would like to have 1. 5. 2024 - without 0 and with spaces between day, month and year together as one field in one line. In word I get 05.01
2024 - in two rows.
Thank you very much.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

= MONTH(A1) & ". " & DAY(A1) & "." & JEAR(A1)

I would like to merge document in word with excel file. I have problem with date field (word document). It does not matter how I wrote mergefield in word, I get date format in two lines. I do not want that. I Want format 1.(space)5.(space)2024 - without leading 0 in day and month and one space after dot. In excel I have field as text.
